# How to remove or resize a Google map in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, google-maps

I have followed [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xnp2B0JBD_Y) video tutorial to insert a Google map to an excel document.

My problem: I dont know how to resize the map or remove it. Any help?

NOTE: when I right click on the map, it just shows the browser context menu.

Regards

**SOLVED**: I just have to switch to the Design Mode in the Developer tab.

Javi

Comment: It's good that you post your answer as such. It improves SO for other users.